# Suffering and Punishment

Tags: gods

We get a life based on our past life. If we have done something bad in our past life, we suffer in this life and so on and so forth.

But my question is, after death also, if we have done something bad, we go to Hell and suffer. Then why do we get a bad life in our next life?

Comment: Don't think about suffering and punishment. Think about God. The Astavakra Samhita (1.11) says: "He who considers himself free is free indeed, and he who considers himself bound remain bound. 'As one thinks, so one becomes' is a popular saying in this world, and it is quite true." Think of God and be free. Think of suffering and punishment and you will get suffering and punishment....

Comment: But my question still remains answered. That we all know that if we think of suffering and punishment,we will get suffering and punishment. This even my grand mother and mother told me.